# Stop TS including import of definition file in output

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a 3rd party library that is loaded dynamically with an authentication key.

It's quite a complicated API, so I want type definitions in my TypeScript code.

In my `.tsconfig` I'm using `"target": "esnext"` and `"module": "esnext"`.

With a type definition `typings/third.party.d.ts` I have this in my TS code:

```
import * as third_party from './typings/third.party';
```

The problem is that ends up in the JS output - I don't want it to be and it shouldn't be when the source file is a `.d.ts`.

I've tried including the extension:

```
import * as third_party from './typings/third.party.d.ts';
```

But this makes TS error code TS2691: *"An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing './typings/third.party' instead."*

I've tried adding:

```
/// <reference path="typings/third.party.d.ts" />
```

To the top of the file instead, but then it isn't found at all.

I know I can hack about this with various bundlers, but I don't want the dependency - I want the TS compiler to enforce the definition from the `.d.ts` file but not try to include in the export `.js` file at all.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can import the individual types from the library, or potentially get the whole third party class type, rather than importing everything?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see that in the JS output, TS usually doesn't emit unused imports or imports only used as type annotation. You could also try creating a global type definition that simply exposes the third party types on global.

Comment: @Richard `third.party.d.ts` is around 3000 LoC and maintained from an npm types package - editing it is impractical.

Comment: @Aaron I wouldn't either, but these definitions _are_ used as they describe libraries loaded globally. It's an older API I'm trying to make work with more modern code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but I'm not sure whether it is a bug so would rather have a complete answer.

The `typings/third.party.d.ts` file contains an `export = ...` statement, without which it won't work with `import` statements, however this appears to be what stops it working with `/// <reference path=...` declarations.

It looks like `/// <reference path=...` won't work with anything that includes an explicit default module definition (though it can include `export module` and `export class`).

It also looks like `import` is treated as an output dependency even if the file is explicitly `.d.ts`, which I think might be a bug in TS.